# is_valid() returns True but modelform won't be saved

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have these models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery",blank=True,null=True)

class News(Gallery):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100) 
   #some other fields
```

U know that with this inheritance,News model has a `gallery_ptr` field,now I'm going to update this field using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'{% url DrHub.views.editNews dr.webSite,news.pk %}',
    type:'POST',
    data:{id_HeadImage:$('#id_HeadImage').val(),id_title:$('#id_title').val(),id_category:$('#id_category').val(),id_description:$('#id_description').val()},
})
```

in `views.py` I do this:

```
        gForm=GalleryForm(request.POST['id_HeadImage'], request.FILES,instance=newsInstance.gallery_ptr)
        if gForm.is_valid():
           gForm.save()
        else:
           raise Http404
```

But `Image` of `Gallery` won't be saved,while `is_valid()` is `True`!

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply upload files in ajax like this. Furthermore, I believe $('#id_HeadImage').val() contains only the file name .

Please ref [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The form is valid, but you haven't actually handled the uploaded file (i.e. read and saved it). Have a look at the [example in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#basic-file-uploads).</strike>

You're right, the model form should take care of the uploading for you. [Have you seen this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718429/file-does-not-upload-from-web-form-in-django)? Have you made sure your template declares the form like:

```
<form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

i.e. with `multipart/form-data`

Comment: but I've used modelform to avoid from handling files in this way!

Comment: +1 for "multipart/form-data" although its not the answer here